# Magento2.3.2: Fatal Error on Logout

Tags: fatal-error, magento2.3.2, logout

When I tried to logout, it's showing one error.

> Fatal error: Interface
>   'Webkul\Marketplace\Api\ControllersRepositoryInterface' not found in
>   /home/myusername/public_html/app/code/Webkul/Marketplace/Model/ControllersRepository.php
>   on line 21

My website is [Depoto](https://www.depoto.com)

**My ControllersRepository.php is as follows:**

```php
<?php
/**
 * Webkul Software.
 *
 * @category  Webkul
 * @package   Webkul_Marketplace
 * @author    Webkul
 * @copyright Copyright (c) Webkul Software Private Limited (https://webkul.com)
 * @license   https://store.webkul.com/license.html
 */
namespace Webkul\Marketplace\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Webkul\Marketplace\Model\ResourceModel\Controllers\CollectionFactory;

/** * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects) * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.TooManyFields) */
class ControllersRepository implements \Webkul\Marketplace\Api\ControllersRepositoryInterface
{
    /**     * @var ControllersFactory */
    protected $_controllersFactory;

    /**     * @var Controllers[] */
    protected $_instancesById = [];

    /**     * @var CollectionFactory */
    protected $_collectionFactory;

    /**     * @param ControllersFactory $controllersFactory * @param CollectionFactory     $collectionFactory */
    public function __construct(ControllersFactory $controllersFactory, CollectionFactory $collectionFactory)
    {
        $this->_controllersFactory = $controllersFactory;
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    /**     * {@inheritdoc} */
    public function getById($controllersId)
    {
        $controllersData = $this->_controllersFactory->create();
        /* @var \Webkul\Marketplace\Model\ResourceModel\Controllers\Collection $controllersData */
        $controllersData->load($controllersId);
        if (!$controllersData->getId()) {           // seller controller does not exist           //throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('Requested controller doesn\'t exist'));            $this->_instancesById[$controllersId] = $controllersData;        }      $this->_instancesById[$controllersId] = $controllersData;
            return $this->_instancesById[$controllersId];
        }
    }

    /**     * {@inheritdoc} */
    public function getByModuleName(
        $moduleName = null
    ) {
        $controllersCollection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()
            ->addFieldToFilter('module_name', $moduleName);
        $controllersCollection->load();

        return $controllersCollection;
    }

    /**     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getByPath(
        $controllerPath = null
    ) {
        $controllersCollection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()
            ->addFieldToFilter('controller_path', $controllerPath);
        $controllersCollection->load();

        return $controllersCollection;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getList()
    {
        /** @var \Webkul\Marketplace\Model\ResourceModel\Controllers\Collection $collection */
        $collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create();
        $collection->load();

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think "Webkul\Marketplace\Api\ControllersRepositoryInterface.php" file is missing in the module. So please check that file is in your module or not. If that file is missing, then get the file and add the file in your module "Webkul\Marketplace\Api\ControllersRepositoryInterface.php" path.

Comment: You was missing a closing curly bracket at `getById()`. Not sure if that was a copy/paste mistake or if it's an issue.

Comment: 'Webkul\Marketplace\Api\' check with this path file is missing 'ControllersRepositoryInterface.php'.

Answer (score 3):

I think "Webkul\Marketplace\Api\ControllersRepositoryInterface.php" file is missing in the module.

So please check that file is in your module or not. If that file is missing, then get the file and add the file in your module

"Webkul\Marketplace\Api\ControllersRepositoryInterface.php" path.

After that, run `php bin/magento cache:flush` command and check.